# Selenium - chromedriver is not executable

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have `chromedriver` in `resources/driver` folder of Web Application with executable permission:

```
➜  drivers git:(master) ✗ ls -l chromedriver
-rwxrwxrwx  1 arpitaggarwal  staff  11042904 Jul 29 20:14 chromedriver
➜  drivers git:(master) ✗
```

When I am packaging it as .war, Maven put driver file in `classes/drivers` folder with permission:

```
➜  drivers  ls -l chromedriver
-rw-r--r--  1 arpitaggarwal  staff  11042904 Aug 11 17:49 chromedriver
```

Which is resulting in `IllegalStateException` as below:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable:
>   /Users/arpitaggarwal/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/App/WEB-INF/classes/drivers/chromedriver

Any idea on how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the rationale of putting chrome driver in a war file ? Executable on a web server is not a good idea.

Comment: I am building up a webapp which use selenium for automation testing and selenium needs chrome driver executable, that's the reason I packaged it inside war. Is there any good alternative for the same?

Comment: Does the Automation run on the server where the war is deployed ?

Comment: A simple alternative is to put the chrome driver outside the war file and update the path in the webapp

Comment: @lost: yes, Automation will be running on the server where war will be deployed. And `update the path in the webapp` will result is hard code of path which may differ for different operating system.